Adding a new "finish" button in Vuetify v-stepper-actions
I want to add a FINISH option in the last steps of the v-stepper process.
v-stepper-actions documentation does not help much.
<v-stepper v-model="step">
  <!-- Stepper Header -->
  <v-stepper-header>
    <v-stepper-item title="" value="1"></v-stepper-item>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-stepper-item title="" value="2"></v-stepper-item>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-stepper-item title="" value="3"></v-stepper-item>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-stepper-item title="" value="4"></v-stepper-item>
  </v-stepper-header>

  <!-- Stepper Windows -->
  <v-stepper-window>
    <v-stepper-window-item value="1">
      <v-card title="Choose A" flat>
        <!-- A selection -->
        <v-radio-group v-model="selectedA">
          <v-radio
            v-for="(item, index) in itemsA"
            :key="index"
            :label="item"
            :value="item"
          ></v-radio>
        </v-radio-group>
      </v-card>
    </v-stepper-window-item>

    <v-stepper-window-item value="2">
      <v-card title="Choose B" flat>
        <!-- B selection -->
        <v-radio-group v-model="selectedB">
          <v-radio
            v-for="(item, index) in itemsB"
            :key="index"
            :label="item"
            :value="item"
          ></v-radio>
        </v-radio-group>
      </v-card>
    </v-stepper-window-item>

    <v-stepper-window-item value="3">
      <v-card title="Choose C" flat>
        <!-- C selection -->
        <v-radio-group v-model="selectedC">
          <v-radio
            v-for="(item, index) in itemsC"
            :key="index"
            :label="item"
            :value="item"
          ></v-radio>
        </v-radio-group>
      </v-card>
    </v-stepper-window-item>

    <v-stepper-window-item value="4">
      <v-card title="Details" flat>
        <!-- Details input -->
        <v-text-field v-model="name" hide-details="auto" label="Name"></v-text-field>
        <v-radio-group v-model="selectedD" label="D Size" class="mt-8">
          <v-radio label="aD" value="1"></v-radio>
          <v-radio label="bD" value="2"></v-radio>
          <v-radio label="cD" value="3"></v-radio>
        </v-radio-group>
      </v-card>
    </v-stepper-window-item>
  </v-stepper-window>

  <!-- Stepper Actions -->
  <v-stepper-actions @click:next="customActionForNext" @click:prev="customActionForPrev">
    <template #prev="{ props }">
      <v-btn @click="() => props.onClick()">Back</v-btn>
    </template>
    <template #next="{ props }">
      <v-btn @click="() => props.onClick()">Next</v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-stepper-actions>
</v-stepper>

I read the documentation and tried several approaches, didn't find anything useful.
I just need in the last step instead of next to be "finished" and be able to launch a method.

We can change the button text by passing next-text or previous-text props to the v-stepper component. But, changing the action text for a specific step is not possible in v-stepper.
You can achieve this by passing a conditional prop to the v-stepper. You can define a variable selected(in the below code) and make its default value to the value of the stepper item(here 3) and then change the text of the last stepper component to Finish, also you need to update the selected value programatically using method and need to define a method that will update the selected value whenever the update:modalValue event is emitted.
For customising the click action, you can override the :onClick:next prop.
<v-stepper
  :next-text="selected === 3 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'"
  :items="['Step 1', 'Step 2', 'Step 3']"
  @update:modelValue="valueChanged($event)"
>...</v-stepper>

// method
valueChanged(event) {
  this.selected = event
}


You can achieve this by overriding the next slot.


<template v-slot:next>
    <v-btn @click="next" :disabled="false" variant="text">{{nextButton}}</v-btn>
 </template>



next is a computed property that determines the button label. You can   for example do the following


const selectedStepper = ref(1)
const nextButton = computed(() => selectedStepper.value === 5 ? 'Submit' : 'Next')
const next = () => {
  if (selectedStepper.value < 5) {
    selectedStepper.value += 1;
  }
}

// then pass the selectedStepper as a v-model to the v-stepper like this <v-stepper v-model="selectedStepper"



